# How to wait for the firebase pushtoken in android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase notifications. There are some times when I don't get the pushtoken on time. How can I wait for it?

```
pushToken = firebaseIDService.getToken();
//SOME CODE
registerUser(pushToken);
```

So, I just want to stop that function until I get the result of the getToken().

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by you dont get the token on time?

Comment: Since is an async task, getToken start but the rest of the function continues. So, registerUser() is called before getToken returns anything.

Comment: so then put register user in onPostExecute of your async task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token is generated asynchronously, and may be refreshed periodically. To ensure your app uses the latest token, implement `FirebaseInstanceIdService .onTokenRefresh` as shown in the documentation on [monitoring token generation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation):

> The `onTokenRefreshcallback` fires whenever a new token is generated, so calling `getToken` in its context ensures that you are accessing a current, available registration token. Make sure you have added the service to your manifest, then call `getToken` in the context of `onTokenRefresh`, and log the value as shown:
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onTokenRefresh() {
>     // Get updated InstanceID token.
>     String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
>     Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
>
>     // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
>     // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
>     // Instance ID token to your app server.
>     sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
> }
> ```

The `sendRegistrationToServer` function in the above snippet is something you'd implement yourself, so likely equivalent to `registerUser` in your code

Comment: How could I implement it with a callback?

Comment: `onTokenRefresh` **is** a callback

Comment: Yes, I understand but I can't access the other class (in which I have the registerUser) from that method. In this class I could create an instance of firebaseIDService (it's what I'm doing) to call getToken. How could I call the other class? I'm sorry if I'm I little slow on this.

Comment: Your `FirebaseInstanceIdService` subclass runs in the background even when there is no activity open, so it has a different life cycle than it may be used to. You'll have to move the `registerUser()` method into a place where it can be called from `onTokenRefresh()`.

Answer (score 0):

Warning! Don't use it on main thread! 
Also, it's a bad practice (probably), better use answer by @FrankvanPuffelen.
And I'm not sure it's working, but I'm using same approach for few async operations.

```
@WorkerThread
public String getTokeSync(Context context) {
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    if (token != null)
        return token;
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
    filter.addCategory(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
    final CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver br = new FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            lock.countDown();
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
        }
    }
    context.registerReceiver(br, filter);
    lock.await(); // Better use await with timeout
    return token;
}
```